# Unable to use mailto function of email to send form data

Tags: html, forms

I have a form and I want to send its data to my email ID using mailto function email of HTML. however this is not working for me. please suggest me the best way to do this using HTML.

Below is my code.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
Contact us
</title>
<style>
h1
{
margin-top:30px;
text-align:center;
}
td
{
font-weight:bold;
}
</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#cococo">
<h1>
Call us at
<p>
995-3100-995
</h1>
<div style="text-align:center;"><img src="phone.jpg"/></div>
<p><p><p><p>
<h1>Let us contact you..</h1>
<form action"mailto:luthra.vaibhav@gmail.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
<fieldset>
<legend style="text-align:center;"><h2>Your contact details</h2></legend>
<table style="margin-left:40%">
<tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td><input type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Email</td>
<td><input type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Contact No</td>
<td><input type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" value="Contact Me" align="right"></td>
<td><input type="reset" value="Clear All"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's not working about it?

Answer (score 1):

**Try Using PHP Instead.** MAILTO tag is only a link.

File index.html :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
Contact us
</title>
<style>
h1
{
margin-top:30px;
text-align:center;
}
td
{
font-weight:bold;
}
</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#cococo">
<h1>
Call us at
<p>
995-3100-995
</h1>
<div style="text-align:center;"><img src="phone.jpg"/></div>
<p><p><p><p>
<h1>Let us contact you..</h1>
<form action="email.php" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
<fieldset>
<legend style="text-align:center;"><h2>Your contact details</h2></legend>
<table style="margin-left:40%">
<tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="data"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Email</td>
<td><input type="text" name="email"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Contact No</td>
<td><input type="text" name="contact"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" value="Contact Me" align="right"></td>
<td><input type="reset" value="Clear All"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

File email.php :

```
function isEmail($email) {
return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])\.)+(ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i", $email));
}

if($_POST) {
$emailTo = 'email@gmail.com';
$data = addslashes(trim($_POST['email']));
if(!$data) {
$array = array();
$array['valid'] = 0;
$array['message'] = 'Insert a valid data!';
echo json_encode($array);
}
else {
$subject = 'Header';
$body = "BODY";
// uncomment this to set the From and Reply-To emails, then pass the $headers variable to the "mail" function below
// $headers = "From: ".$user_token." <" . $user_token . ">" . "\r\n" . "Reply-To: " . $user_token;
mail($emailTo, $subject, $body);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you're missing the equal sign

```
<form action="mailto:luthra.vaibhav@gmail.com" 
      method="post" enctype="text/plain">
```

Comment: Thanks for rectifying however using this I am getting a new email page open with mail to address in to field. whereas I want I data should be sent directly to email address. Is there any way to it?